# How To Redirect Traffic Based On Country Using Maxmind Geoip2 Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, maxmind

I bought Maxmind GeoIP2 a while and I want to do a simple redirect based on Countries but it seems there's no clear answer how to do it even in their website. I am not good in coding but I'm trying to understand how it works...

For example my website is google.com and I want to redirect some countries to yahoo.com, I came up with this code but it redirects everyone to yahoo.com. Can anyone help me or reconstruct this script to make it work for its purpose? Thanks a lot..

```js
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
var user_country = geoip2.country(
    function (response) {
if (response.country.iso_code === "FR"){window.location = "http://yahoo.com"}
else {window.location = "http://google.com"}
if (response.country.iso_code === "BE"){window.location = "http://yahoo.com"}
else {window.location = "http://google.com"}
if (response.country.iso_code === "PH"){window.location = "http://yahoo.com"}
else {window.location = "http://google.com"}

    },
    function (error) {
        // handle error
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see [MaxMind's redirection tutorial](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/#Redirect_Users_to_a_Country-Specific_Site)?

Answer (score 2):

I created a little more sophisticated version based on this [Maxmind Tutorial](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/). You need to [register your domain at Maxmind and purchase credits](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/) to make usage of the GeoIP2 JavaScript Client API (same is true for the solution above!). Have fun!

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

var redirect = (function () {

    /* Get actual URL */
    var url = window.location.href; 

    /* This implements the actual redirection. */
    var redirectBrowser = function (site) {
        var uri = "https://www.example.com/" + site;
        window.location = uri;
    };

    /* These are the country codes for the countries we have sites for.
     * We will check to see if a visitor is coming from one of these countries.
     * If they are, we redirect them to the country-specific site. If not, we
     * redirect them to https://www.example.com/ */
    var sites = {
        "us": {"active": true, "target": "en-us"},
        "gb": {"active": true, "target": "en-gb"},
        "de": {"active": true, "target": "de"},
        "fr": {"active": true, "target": "fr"},
        "fi": {"active": true, "target": "fi"},
        "hu": {"active": true, "target": "hu"},
        "nl": {"active": true, "target": "nl"},
        "se": {"active": true, "target": "sv"}
    };
    var defaultSite = "";

    var onSuccess = function (geoipResponse) {
        /* There's no guarantee that a successful response object
         * has any particular property, so we need to code defensively. */
        if (!geoipResponse.country.iso_code) {
            redirectBrowser(defaultSite);
            return;
        }

        /* ISO country codes are in upper case. */
        var code = geoipResponse.country.iso_code.toLowerCase();

        if ( sites[code].active ) {
            redirectBrowser(sites[code].target);
        }
        else if ( url == defaultSite ) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            redirectBrowser(defaultSite);
        }

    };

    /* We don't really care what the error is, we'll send them
     * to the default site. */
    var onError = function (error) {
        redirectBrowser(defaultSite);
    };

    return function () {
        geoip2.country( onSuccess, onError );
    };
}());

redirect();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work

```
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
geoip2.country(
    function (response) {
        if (response.country.iso_code == "FR") {
            window.location = "http://yahoo.com"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "BE") {
            window.location = "http://yahoo.com"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "PH") {
            window.location = "http://yahoo.com"
        }

        else {
            window.location = "http://google.com"
        }
    }
);
</script>
```